# Posting image to twitter via php class isn't working after media_id received

Tags: php, api, twitter, media

I'm using a Twitter api from https://github.com/dg/twitter-php/tree/master/src

I have an image, who's location is being stored in a variable:

```
$fullImagePath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/imagesToUpload/imageName.png";
```

Once I set that variable, I call the "send" method as follows:

```
$twitter->send('test post', [$fullImagePath]);
```

I've edited the response from "send" method to include the "media_id" information that the method gathers while processing files. This aforementioned post returns the following concerning media files:

```
{ ["media_id"]=> int(1269850838970812345) ["media_id_string"]=> string(19) "1269850838970812345" ["size"]=> int(10717) ["expires_after_secs"]=> int(86400) ["image"]=> array(3) { ["image_type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["w"]=> int(280) ["h"]=> int(498) } }
```

As you can see, Twitter is returning information - mainly, the media_id - but when the post appears on my twitter account. there's no image associated with it.

I've been stuck here for a few hours, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you